# Issue with Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Forwarding across Instances

Tags: activemq-artemis

Artemis v2.6.0

- We are deploying 2 instances (Instance-1 and Instance-2) of Artemis in Master-Master mode.
- We confirmed that both the instances are in a cluster by verifying it on the Artemis portal.
- We created a queue named, queue-1 on both Instances.
- A Producer is binded on Instance-1 and a Consumer is binded on Instance-2.
- Case:1

  - When Consumers are connected to Instance-2 and Producer is connected to Instance-1.

    - Expected Behavior:
      Consumer should receive the message that are produced by Producer.
    - Actual Behavior:
      No messages are received by Consumer.
      However, we can see the Message Acknowledge Count equal to the Total Message Count.
      It was also observed that the Message Count on another queue named, $.artemis.internal.sf.{cluster_name}.{node_id}, showed the Total Messages that were produced by the Producer.
- Case:2

  - When Consumers are connected to both Instance-1 and Instance-2.

    -Expected Behavior:
    Consumers on both the instances should receive the messages.

    -Actual Behavior
    Consumer on the Instance-1 where producer is binded, receives 50% of the messages.
    The consumer on the Instance-2, where the producer is not binded, is not receiving any messages.
    However, we can see the Message Acknowledge Count equal to the Total Message Count.
    It was also observed that the Message Count on another queue named, $.artemis.internal.sf.{cluster_name}.{node_id}, showed 50% of the Total Messages that were produced by the Producer.

Conclusion:
It seems that, the messages are forwarded to another instance but are not reflected in the queue present on that instance even though the Acknowledgement is received.

Comment: Can you provide the `broker.xml` from both instances? Also, is your consumer using a selector?

Comment: Please provide the logs from both instances which include the broker startup.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on the latest release of ActiveMQ Artemis (i.e. 2.16.0)?

Answer (score 0):

I was deploying the Artemis on Kubernetes.
The issue was with the Helm Chart that was used to deploy and configure Artemis on Kubernetes.
Following is the correct Helm Chart:
https://github.com/vromero/activemq-artemis-helm
Note: Use master branch of this project